# Indian visa re-entry and cancellation

Tags: visas, india, uk-citizens, cancellations

I have a question regarding a tourist Visa. I am from the Channel Island, and have a British Passport and I would like to apply for a tourist visa to go to Goa for 2 weeks in November. I know usually a 6 month tourist Visa is issued, but I would like to know what will happen when I return to England in late  November, as I would then like to head back out to India from January for 6 months on a new Tourist Visa (as I will have returned back to the UK in November and will reside there until January). Will this be possible?

Your advise would be greatly appreciated,

Comment: Just need to specify at the time of application that you need a multiple entry visa. One multiple entry visa would cost you less and would save you a trip to the Indian embassey.

Answer (score 2):

I have gotten several multiple-entry and single-entry visa over the last years. It works as follows:

Both visa types have a start & expiry date. With a multiple entry visa, you can enter and exit as often as you like within the timeframe. If you get a single-entry visa, you can enter anytime within the timeframe, and when you do so, a stamp with the immigration date will be placed on the visa to invalidate it. Then you can only exit the country. If you try to re-enter, that visa will not be valid anymore.

Therefore, you will either have to get a multiple entry visa or several single entry visa.